# Magento 500 error

Tags: magento, categories, 500px

I need some help and suggestions.
I ve a site austral5.nextmp.net  with 16 (all) configurable products each with 3500+ simple products. and I created all simple products with the extension --
https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/simple-products-generator.html

product creation was ok. but problem is-- if a category has lots of configurable products (10+), this category page shows 500 error in front end. the Hosting server is Nexcess.

Please experts, give me some solutions.

thanks a lot

Comment: can you see any errors on the error logs? system.log, exception.log and also check on your server's php logs

Comment: yes. in system.log only one error----- Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()  in /app/code/local/ARW/Bauhaus/Helper/Data.php on line 294

Comment: Looks like the error is coming from a custom module 'Bauhaus' but is difficult to say more without looking at the code. Try debugging that file, and see what values are going to that foreach statement

Comment: hi, its not important extension. I disabled it and problem remain same.

Comment: hmm i see. any other errors on the logsthat might seem related? Can you check php errors on your host too?

Comment: Have a look at your SERVER error logs (i.e. Apache/Nginx) -  the 500 means you won't find anything in error logs of Magento as it didn't hit the application (assuming it's not a Magento error page).  If it is, check the exception.log.  I'd guess you're either running out of memory, or time.